# How to get row from database MySQL using python?

Tags: python, mysql

I try to get the row. I receive error like "mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.". How can I change my code to work properly? I am using python 3.7.4 and MySQL 8.0. My package is mysql.connector

```
statement = "SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'"
name = input("")
passwd = input("")
mycursor.execute(statement, name, passwd)
users = mycursor.fetchall()
print(users)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `mycursor.execute(statement, name, passwd)` to `mycursor.execute(statement, (name, passwd))`

And..

`fetchall()` method will fetch all the results. So you can do like this:

```py
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
print("Username : ", rows[0][0], "Password : ", row[0][1])
```